# Free Radius upgrade Issues

Tags: upgrade, freeradius

I recently upgraded my Free Radius code from 2.0 to 3.x build. I am looking for some of the APIs supported by older Free Radius versions. I am looking for APIs ldap_pairget(). Can you please let me know what APIs should be used in place of ldap_pairget. ALso these function include pairmake(), pairadd(), pairdelete() APIs which are not available in newe Free Radius Code. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some examples from your code of calling those functions and I should be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: ldap_pairget is used to Get RADIUS attributes from LDAP object. This ldap_pairget internally calls pairmake(), pairadd(), pairdelete() functions. If Free Radius 3.x version is providing a different API for ldap_pairget function then please suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

In v3.0.x theres a concept of "tmpls" (templates) and maps.  Templates describe a data source or sink, and maps describe how to move data from one tmpl to another.  There are still the low level pair move functions.

- Pair allocation `fr_pair_alloc`.
- Assigning value from string `fr_pair_value_from_str`.
- Add a pair to a list `fr_pair_add`.
- Replace an existing pair in a list `fr_pair_replace`.
- Delete a pair by its protocol number `fr_pair_delete_by_num`.

The equivalent function to `ldap_pairget` in v3.0.x is `fr_ldap_map_do`, but it's not designed to be used by external callers.  It'll work, but it's a lot of effort to feed it the structures it expects.

In general, if you have user configurable mappings you should call `map_to_request`, and pass it the callback it needs to get values for the pairs being created.